# Getting a 1200px page to display correctly on a smartphone

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to get a 1200px page to display in a Samsung S7.  Since the S7 has a 1440x2560 screen I would expect the page to display fine,  but all I see is about the left quarter of it,  with no ability to swipe left to see more.  I tried adding  a viewport meta tag:

```
<head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

but I get the same results.   Does anyone know how to get this page to display correctly?

The page I'm trying to display is at    https://thebarcoderegistry.com/verify/?barcode=040232534218

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper has `overflow-x: hidden;` Therefore the internal content is cut off when the width of #wrapper on the mobile phone is narrower than the width of the internal content.

Take `overflow-x: hidden;` off or change it to `visible` and you will be able to scroll to see the content.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  But I'm not seeing `overflow-x: hidden;` anywhere in the "View Page Source" looking at the page on a desktop with Chrome. Could you tell me how you found that?

Comment: when you inspect in chrome dev tools scale your browser width to less than 767px.  The style is within a media query:
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
#wrapper {
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

Comment: This is strange! With the page scaled down to 640x960 or 768x1280 View Page Source on my desktop still doesn't show anything like `overflow-x: hidden;` Plus, I wrote the HTML and CSS for the page and I know I didn't put any media querys in it. How can I see what you're seeing?

Comment: Are you using a theme?  The style comes from a file called style.css.  The top of the style file says "Theme Name: Canvas Theme URI: http://www.woothemes.com/ ..."  I found this style by opening Chrome Developer Tools and docking it to the right.  I then scaled the browser window width to about 500px.  I selected the div with the id="wrapper" in the elements tab of the tools and saw this style I mentioned.  Next to the style is the reference to line 1837 of style.css.

Comment: Got it!  This is a WordPress page and while I created the template that generates it, the whole thing is controlled by the parent Canvas theme and it's style.css. Thanks for your patience.